# gdb watchpoint except when triggered in specific locations?

Tags: gdb, watchpoint

I have a variable getting corrupted.  I want to see where this is happening, so a watchpoint is the obvious choice, except this variable frequently gets set (in this case, processing network packets and it gets set once for each packet).  I would like to exempt the watchpoint from the location where the variable is *supposed* to get written.  Basically, what I would like is "watch variable if line_number != x"; the gdb docs seem to be a bit thin on the conditional expressions, so I'm not sure this is possible...

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this, in the following source file.

```
struct stuff {
  int watched;
};

void dont_hit(struct stuff *foo) {
  begin:
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      foo->watched = i;
  end:
   return;
}

void hit(struct stuff *foo) {
  foo->watched = 1024;
}

int main()
{
  struct stuff foo;

  setup:
    dont_hit(&foo);
    hit(&foo);
    dont_hit(&foo);
}
```

We can then use the watchpoint condition: if $pc != ...
as shown below:

```
(gdb) break main
(gdb) r
(gdb) watch foo.watched
(gdb) c
Hardware watchpoint 2: foo.watched

Old value = -8320
New value = 0
dont_hit (foo=0x7fffffffde90) at main.c:7
7      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
(gdb) p $pc
$1 = (void (*)()) 0x4004c0 <dont_hit+26>
(gdb) watch -location foo->watched if $pc != 0x4004c0
ardware watchpoint 3: -location foo->watched
(gdb) delete 2
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 3: -location foo->watched

Old value = 99
New value = 1024
hit (foo=0x7fffffffde90) at main.c:15
```

Another way is to use breakpoints to enable/disable the watchpoint in places we don't want it to trigger, I'm using the label's here setup/begin/end for clarity, but you can replace main:label with filename:line_number

```
break main:setup
run
watch -location foo.watched
break dont_hit:begin
commands
  silent
  disable 2
  cont
end

break dont_hit:end
commands
  silent
  enable 2
  cont
end
```

A third way, is going to use Python, and FinishBreakpoints to do the enabling/disabling.

Comment: I tried "watch orig_pktlen if $_ != 0x8049831" (address being the address it was at when the watchpoint tripped) and it ran for a while then gave: Recursive internal problem.
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Same result using $pc instead of $_

Comment: That's indicative of some bad problem in gdb.  Hard to say what without a reproducer.  Anyway this was a good answer and this technique does work.